# Spinner does not show b/c the bound variable is not updated

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I'm working on a Blazor server side app. The page has a table with a list of cars and some filter elements on top. When I select a filter, a spinner should be visible until the new data is fetched and rendered.

The spinner with its variable:

```
<div class="spinner-border @spinner" role="status">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
</div>

@code{
string spinner = "invisible";

    public string vehicleTypeFilter
    {
        set
        {
            _vehicleTypeFilter = value;            
            ApplyFilters();
        }
        get { return _vehicleTypeFilter; }
    }
}
```

The select for the Baumuster (vehicleType) is bound to the vehicleTypeFilter variable:

```
<div class="col-md-2 form-floating">
        <select class="form-control" @bind="vehicleTypeFilter">
            <option value="" selected>Alle</option>
            @foreach (var vehicleType in vehicleTypes.OrderBy(x => x.Description))
            {
                <option value="@vehicleType.Description">@vehicleType.Description</option>
            }
        </select>
        <label>Baumuster</label>
    </div>
```

Then a value is selected, the ApplyFilter method is triggered through the setter of the vehicleTypeFilter variable:

```
public void ApplyFilters()
{
        ToggleSpinner();
        // I also tried a StateHasChanged(); right here

        // 1. Get all cars
        cars = model.CreateIndexViewModel();
      
        // 2. Filter for Baumuster / vehicle type
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vehicleTypeFilter))
        {
            cars.viewModels = cars.viewModels.Where(x => x.VehicleDescription == vehicleTypeFilter).ToList();
        }

        ToggleSpinner();
}
```

The ToggleSpinner method:

```
public void ToggleSpinner()
    {
        if (spinner == "invisible" )
            spinner = "";
        else
            spinner = "invisible";
    }
```

Unfortunately, I don't see the spinner. When  I inspect the html page right after the breakpoint hits the Baumuster-filter, the value of spinner is still set to "invisible". I even tried to call `StateHasChanged();` after the first `ToggleSpinner()` but that didn't help.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a spinner at all?  Which part of ApplyFilters() takes time and then why isn't that part `async`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you want async behaviour from a synchronous property. The standard advice is against `async void` but if you want to stay with the property, the minimal change would be:

```
public async void ApplyFilters()
{
   ToggleSpinner();
   // I also tried a StateHasChanged(); right here
   StateHasChanged();   // this _requests_ an update
   await Task.Delay(1); // this is why you need async void

   ... as before

   ToggleSpinner();
   StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend `async Task` anyway.

Comment: d00d can await Task.Delay(<milliseconds>) at any point for visual effect.

Comment: I think I just ninja-edited my last comment.  If it's a very fast routine, I think instead of having a spinner at all, he might want to use a `ShowMessageText(); StateHasChanged(); await Task.Delay(2000); HideMessageText();` pattern instead.

Comment: I tried the solution of Henk with a ToggleSpinner(); await Task.Delay(1); StateHasChanged(); at the very beginning and the same at the very end of the ApplyFilters() method and it does what i wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - `async Task` requires an async context to call it from. There isn't one here. Not awaiting an `async task` is worse imho.

Comment: Yeah good point.  The whole idea of starting this in a setter kind of invalidates the idea of making it all `async` anyway.  Seeing what d00d is trying to do, I'd probably skip the 2-way `bind`, and handle the text change in an `async Task` event handler instead (probably checking for "Enter" key in a keypress or something).

Comment: **Never** use `async void`. The only [exception is for event handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). `async void` says I'm going to create some tasks and won't return them to you. So you can't await them? Will they run? Who knows! You don't need `await Task.Delay..` either, use `public Task ApplyFilters()`.. and then `return Task.CompletedTask` in the code

Comment: @Quango - using `Task ApplyFilters()` and then not awaiting it (you can't) is exactly the same as `async void`, just less honest. The problem is not what to return but how to call it.

Comment: And the Task.Delay() is there to update the UI, ansswering the core of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You've shown a lot of code, but I don't see `ToggleSpinner`

However, you call it twice in your `ApplyFilters` method, with no blocking calls, so I'd assume that it's turning the spinner on and off so fast that it doesn't render (or at least that you can't notice it).

If the methods you call in `ApplyFilters` actually take any time, then Henk's got the right idea-- except you should use `async Task` I think.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the method to my posting.